# Bing Maps API in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bing-maps

Using .Net framework to building application. I have created a Bing Maps API service in Azure and I want to integrate it in a chat bot created using Bot Framework. I have generated the key for using map.

I am able to show list of locations based on a keyword. I am using `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?form={FormCode}&q={keyword}&key={BingKey}`. It works fine and I am able to see the locations as Maps.

Now I want to search things like `doctors near me` or something like this. However I am not able get any reference of it. Its very confusing. I am not sure how to do it. Could anyone please guide me on this?

With some reading, maybe we have search data by passing key and data source ID however I am not sure how to create Data Source for Bing Maps.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Points of Interest (POI) so you have to use `Bing Spatial Data Services`.

There are several Data Sources available:

- **FourthCoffeeSample** which is a sample datasource
- **NAVTEQNA** for POI provided by NAVTEQ for North America
- **NAVTEQEU** for POI provided by NAVTEQ for Europe
- etc.

Each DataSource has a different base URL:

- FourthCoffeeSample: http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/20181f26d9e94c81acdf9496133d4f23/FourthCoffeeSample/FourthCoffeeShops
- NAVTEQNA: https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/f22876ec257b474b82fe2ffcb8393150/NavteqNA/NavteqPOIs
- NAVTEQEU: http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/c2ae584bbccc4916a0acf75d1e6947b4/NavteqEU/NavteqPOIs

How to make a query? The syntax's documentation is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx)

You may also be interested by some references:

- EntityTypes list for NAVTEQEU and NAVTEQNA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478191.aspx

There is also an example of use of these API [here](https://www.bing.com/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/sdsnearbysearch#JS) (in JS).